# ipad camera interface orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to create iPad camera, before that I create iPhone camera app with portrait orientation.

When I choose photo from album (device album), iPad app throws an error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'`

Here is my code to choose photo from album:

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerController.delegate = self;
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
pickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What must I add to made it accessible from iPad with landscape orientation?

Comment: do you want to use only portrait orientation? what orientation you want to support in your app

Comment: my iphone version show as potrait UI which is ok. my ipad version show as landscape UI, which previously has problem when try to get photo from device album which need potrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

i found solution, case closed.
i add in my *appdelegate.m*:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else  /* iphone */
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: Good! But please note that you could have done that same thing the way I said - by editing the _Info.plist_. It has one group of settings for iPad and one group of settings for iPhone. So you could have done this with no code at all, just by checking the correct checkboxes in the target editor, as shown in my screen shot. There's nothing wrong with the way you did it, however.

Comment: if i edited info.plist become all device orientation, my ipad app become uncontrol, because i create my app with landscape UI.so landscape will show when xib and storyboard called by user. but in some case like get photo from device album which need potrait orientation, my ipad app will show it as potrait orientation. so, i did not need to change device orientation on every view controller.

Comment: If you do not listen, you will not learn. It would work exactly the same way. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine but when we are launching the application it show portrait on left.. So please tell how we can restrict all portrait event. -(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;else  /* iphone */returnUIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}